# Spring Java Config: configure already existing bean

Tags: spring, spring-java-config

I want to configure in my `@Configuration` class bean which is already created by other library's autoconfiguration. I just need to change some fields in that class after it's being initialized.

But I can't find a proper way how to provide code block in `@Configuration` class and not using `@Bean` annotation. Is there an ideomatic way to do so in spring?

Comment: You need to use a bean post processor.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way to do this:

```
@Configuration
class TestConfig {
    @Autowired
    private SomeBean someBean;

    @PostConstruct
    private void initSomeBean() {
       // someBean.setProperty("qwe");
    }
}
```

`@PostConstruct` annotation defines init-method, which is getting called after `SomeBean` is autowired. In this method you can adjust your bean

Comment: Yes, this looks like what I needed.

Comment: So simple, so obvious, yet so good. Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for as well.

Comment: @IgorKonoplyanko Could I take the bean as a parameter of initSomeBean() and remove the `@Autowired` annotation?

Comment: @AdoniasAlcântara I am afraid that it will not work. Bot definetely worth trying

Comment: @AdoniasAlcântara No you can't, because the `@PostConstruct` cannot have any arguments (you will get a "Lifecycle method annotation requires a no-arg method" error if you try it anyway). You can use constructor injection instead of field injection to make it a little better though :P.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to import one Config in AnotherConfig on? It can be done via annotation placed on AnotherConfig:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
...
@Import(value = {Config.class})
public class AnotherConfig ... {}
```

Comment: No, Generally speaking I need to just have some code block in @Configuration which doesnt return a value, just takes a bean and adjusts it.

Comment: so, the bean is defined in the same config. Why can't you configure the bean in the method where it gets created?