# Not able to add module com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I am currently using Spring `v3.0.5` along with `jackson-databind:2.12.3` and `jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.15.2`.

I have tried adding the module by following the usage from the [official repository](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime#usage) by creating a Bean in my Configuration class like this:

```
package org.something.config;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
                .addModule(new JavaTimeModule())
                .build();

        return mapper;
    }

}
```

I am still getting the same error when trying to send a request:
`Java 8 date/time type 'java.time.Duration' not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to enable handling`

Comment: Looks like the preconfigured bean is being picked up. Is `org.something.config` being scanned? If it is, you can try with `@Primary` on your ObjectMapper to ensure it is the one selected.

Comment: @Chaosfire yup it's being scanned and it is also present in the application context. I tried adding `@Primary` but still it is not being picked up.

Comment: Hmm, then you can try to configure already existing bean as explained here - [Spring Java Config: configure already existing bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57920642/spring-java-config-configure-already-existing-bean).

Answer (score 0):

I changed to model class to add the annotation `@JsonSerialize(using = DurationSerializer.class)` to the Duration field which resolved this issue.